# Gmail api asking for credentials after classified with liferay

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, gmail-api

I have one portlet in liferay which is getting user emails from gmail using web service. I have classified gmail with liferay. It means when I am login into liferay portal, user is automatically login inside gmail.

Now the problem I am facing is, let's say user has cleared the browser history, cookies,  everything. After then user opens liferay portal and login into it. So user will be automatically login inside gmail. Up to here it's fine. After that when I click on my portlet, it is calling the gmail webservice for getting emails. As I am already logged in into the gmail, this web service should not ask me for the gmail crendentials again. But it's asking. Let's say if I open "https://mail.google.com/a/edsoa.com" (this is a specific domain url provided by gmail) once in a browser programatically, so it will create a gmail session in browser and after that if I access gmail web service then it will not ask me for the credentials.

So my main concern is, is there any way that I can create gmail session in browser without opening "https://mail.google.com/a/edsoa.com" in browser.

In short what I want to achieve is that if I am already logged in inside gmail, then gmail should never ask me for the credentials even for accessing any gmail web service.

Any help would really be appreciated as I am running out of time.

Thanks and Regards,
Abdulbasit F Shaikh.

Answer (score 0):

You say that you're accessing gmail through a web service, but refer to the browser being logged in/out - I don't really get your problem: If you're accessing the gmail API (I'm not familiar with it), this is probably independent of the server login.

I'd expect the login to gmail webservice API to be originating from the (Liferay) server, while your browser's identification is - naturally - originating in your browser. Thus, there's no way to initiate a browser session from the (Liferay) server.

You can however try to sign in to Liferay with OpenID - AFAIK google offers this as well. This means you'd provide your credentials to google in order to log in to Liferay. And most likely this will also sign you in to gmail (provided you use the same account)

Comment: Thanks Olaf for your answer. I got the solution for question mentioned but again in trouble which somewhat relates to question posted. I have one application in liferay which contains all the mails from gmail. Now when I click on any email, it is redirecting me to actual gmail and opens up the mail on which I clicked. But this is only happening if "https://mail.google.com/a/edsoa.com" hits atleast one time in the browser. But let's say I have cleared my browser cookies. So no gmail cookies exist in browser.

Comment: Now if I click on email from my applicaiton, it will redirect me to "https://mail.google.com/u/0/#inbox" but will not open up my mail which I clicked because this is first time gmail is loading. After that if you clicked on any email, it will open properly. So my main concern is is there any way that after clearing the cookies, if I am clicking on mail from applicaiton, first time also it should open up the mail in gmail.

Comment: This is more a question of google handling URLs coming from outside of its own domain - and if it remembers which page you requested before you signed in. IMHO this has nothing to do with Liferay, only with google - therefor I'm out, sorry, I don't know how they handle their URLs.